# Weird lambda behaviour in list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, list-comprehension

I'm playing with lambda functions inside of list comprehension, and found some weird behaviour

```
x = [(lambda x: i) for i in range(3)]

print(x[0](0)) #print 2 instead of 0
print(x[1](0)) #print 2 instead of 1
print(x[2](0)) #print 2
```

Can someone explain why the result is not that I expect?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`lambda`s bind variables themselves, not the values that they had. `i` is changed to `2` at the end of the list comprehension, so all the `lambda`s refer to `i` at that point, and thus refer to 2.

To avoid this, you can use the *default argument trick*:

```
[lambda x,i=i:i for i in range(3)]
```

This binds the value of `i` in the default argument (which is evaluated at function definition time).

Comment: +1 for clarity and brevity

Comment: `[lambda x,j=i:j for i in range(3)]` would be even clearer.

Comment: if you want to use lambda to define a function, then apply a variable to it. The variable in the lambda is not what the OP thinks it is, despite having the same symbol. So this is probably what the OP wants:  

`[ (lambda a:a)(i) for i in range(3)]`