# strange behavior with lamba: getattr(obj, x) inside a list

Tags: python, list, lambda, getattr

In the following example:

```
class A(object):
    pass
    prop1 = 1
    prop2 = 2
    prop3 = 3
    prop4 = 4

obj = A()
tmp = ['prop1', 'prop2', 'prop3', 'prop4']
getter = [ lambda: getattr(obj, x) for x in tmp ]
```

I am always getting `4` when calling the `getter`:

```
[getter[i]() for i in range(4)]
#[4, 4, 4, 4]
```

why!?

Comment: Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11109838/weird-closure-behavior-in-python

Comment: Dup : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15814595/weird-lambda-behaviour-in-list-comprehension

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do here, but you might want to look at `operator.attrgetter`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a very common problem with lambdas.  Ultimately, the variable `x` is looked up when the function is called, not when it is created.  As such, at the end of your loop, the value of `x` is `'prop4'` and all your lambdas will give you the same thing.

The commonly proposed fix is to use a default argument in your lambda.  It gets evaluated when the function is created.

```
lambda x=x: getattr(obj,x)
```

Comment: @sgpc -- Yep.  I added the commonly proposed fix.

Comment: Not just with lambdas; functions have closures too, but people run into it more often with lambdas.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I think I have an answer to a dupe of this somewhere that starts by explaining the behavior with functions ...

Comment: `(lambda z: lambda : getattr(obj,z))(x)` works too, and does not have an optional parameter.

Comment: Ahh, not quite a dupe:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/11953356/748858 but a very related question.

Comment: @Elazar -- Wow... I don't even want to try to figure out if that will work.  That looks like some kind of functional programming to me :-P

Comment: @mgilson: So do I! Fancy that.. :-P

Comment: @mgilson, Elazar's comment is a closure as opposed to the default argument trick

Comment: @gnibbler -- Yeah, that's what I was assuming was happening there.  It's just, significantly more difficult for me to parse and so I was too lazy to bother ;-)