# strange behavior of a function in for loop

Tags: python, lambda

I am trying to write a python function(al), which would generate a series, for example

```
   f(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + ... + x^n
```

given number of terms in the series. (Remember, the above is only an example of one such series.) I could do it to some extent as follows

```
def addTwoFunctions(f, g):
    return lambda x : f(x) + g(x)
```

It works okay if I now do it the dumb way:

```
// initialize h as a function
h = lambda x : 0*x

print h(2)                            # output = 0 

// first term in the series "1"
g = lambda x : x**0
h = addTwoFunctions(h, g)
print h(2)                            # output = 1

// second term  "x"
g = lambda x : x**1
h = addTwoFunctions(h, g)
print h(2)                            # output = 3

// third term "x^2"
g = lambda x : x**2
h = addTwoFunctions(h, g)
print h(2)                            # output = 7
```

This creates correct outputs (as shown with the comments). However if I put it in a for loop

```
print h(2)

for i in range(3) :
    g = lambda x: x**i
    h = addTwoFunctions(h,g)
    print h(2)
    pass
```

It generates output as

```
 0
 1
 4
 12
```

as if the function h gets doubled at each entry in the for loop. Am I doing something wrong here?

Thanks in advance,
Nikhil

Comment: I answered basically the exact same question earlier today ... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17192226/strange-behavior-with-lamba-getattrobj-x-inside-a-list/17192263#17192263

Comment: @mgilson: and it has been answered many times before. we need a good dupe target.

Comment: @MartijnPieters -- I know.  But twice in a day isn't quite so common ;-)

Comment: lambdas are just one-expression anonymous functions, so the same principles apply; `i` is looked up when the lambda is *called*, not when it is defined.

Comment: aah... Thanks a lot you guys. I did know this caveat of lambdas, I just forgot to look at that "i" :p... Thanks once again!

@mgilson, +1'd your answer at the link!

Comment: and now I am stumped :(... I now don't see an obvious way to generate such a series :(

Comment: @NikhilJJoshi: use a keyword argument to bind the `i` at definition time: `g = Functional(lambda x, i=i: x**i)`